# How do I show only web app logs on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

How do I display only web app logs? Same as on the Heroku website but in the windows terminal.

I use this command and the logs are equal to "All Processes":
heroku logs --app=angelimsystemmotorzone-bling --tail
[image]

But I want the same logs when I filter "web"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by dyno with `--dyno web` in your terminal